# How to merge dictionary with a key to another key dictionary in python?

Tags: python

I want to convert this list

```
level_data = [
    {'level': 0,'connected': 2, , 'total_nodes':5},
    {'level': 1,'connected': 5, , 'total_nodes':2},
    {'level': None,'connected': 1, , 'total_nodes':1},
    ]
```

to this List as output :that means i want to remove the level:None dict and add to level:0 dict

```
level_data = [
    {'level': 0,'connected': 3, , 'total_nodes':6},   #this will be added with contents of level None dictionary 
    {'level': 1,'connected': 5, , 'total_nodes':2},
    ]
```

Problem :if level_data have level:None dict add to level:0 dictionary assuming level_data may have or not level:0
I tried this brute_force approach :

```
for x in level_data:
    if x["level"] == None:
        for y in level_data:
           if y["level"] == 0:
               y["total_nodes"] += x["total_nodes"]
               y["connected"] += x["connected"]
           else:
               level_data.append({
                   "level":0,
                   "total_nodes":x["total_nodes"],
                   "connected":x["connected"]
                    })
```

Comment: Did you mean that you want to remove items where `item['level'] == None`?

Comment: Your question is not clear, what are you trying to do remove items where ``level`` is None ?

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried.

Comment: yes, i wan to remove level:none dict and its other keys value 'connected': 1, , 'total_nodes':1 to add to level:0 dict

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a `merge()` function which will merge all levels together and specifically merge `level:None` with `level:0`

```
def merge(data):
    ret = {}
    for item in data:
        level = item['level']
        if level is None:
            level = 0
        if level in ret:
            node = ret[level]
            node['connected'] += item['connected']
            node['total_nodes'] += item['total_nodes']
        else:
            ret[level] = item
    return [{'level':k, 'connected': v['connected'], 'total_nodes': v['total_nodes']} for (k,v) in ret.items()]
```

So it can be called like this:

```
level_data = [
    {'level': 0,'connected': 2, 'total_nodes':5},
    {'level': 1,'connected': 5, 'total_nodes':2},
    {'level': None,'connected': 1, 'total_nodes':1},
    ]

print(merge(level_data))
```

Output:

```
[{'level': 0, 'connected': 3, 'total_nodes': 6}, {'level': 1, 'connected': 5, 'total_nodes': 2}]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a list comprehension, containing all the dictionaries except ones with the value of `'level'` as `None`, and adding the values from index `2` to `0`:

```
level_data = [
    {'level': 0,'connected': 2, 'total_nodes':5},
    {'level': 1,'connected': 5, 'total_nodes':2},
    {'level': None,'connected': 1, 'total_nodes':1},
    ]
for di in level_data:
    if di['level'] == 0:
        level_data[0].update({'connected':level_data[2]['connected']+level_data[0]['connected'],'total_nodes':level_data[2]['total_nodes']+level_data[0]['total_nodes']})
level_data = [d for d in level_data if d['level'] != None]
print(level_data)
```

Output:

```
[
 {'level': 0, 'connected': 3, 'total_nodes': 6}, 
 {'level': 1, 'connected': 5, 'total_nodes': 2}
]
```

Comment: thanks Ann, i changed my question, there was error in it , please try now

Comment: ATQ "assuming level_data may have or not level:0 "                                                        means  it not certain if list_data[0] will have level:0 dict .so it need some modification..

Answer (score 0):

I Prepared one more solution for this using @Ann solution and improving it.
1.prepare keys list
2.search for None(level) in keys and get its index
3.if keys have 0(level) get its index
    3.1. update 0(level)dict with None(level) dict
4. keys not having 0(level) create new level with complete values of None(level)
--->(it will be great if it can be reduced further)..

```
keys = [x['level'] for x in level_data]
if None in keys:
   pNone = keys.index(None)
   if 0 in keys:
       pZero = keys.index(0)
       level_data[pZero].update(
           {'connected':level_data[pNone]['connected']+level_data[pZero]['connected'],
           'total_nodes':level_data[pNone]['total_nodes']+level_data[pZero]['total_nodes']})
            del level_data[pNone]
   else:
       level_data.append({"level":0,'connected':level_data[pNone]['connected'],'total_nodes':level_data[pNone]['total_nodes']})
```